# Creating and storing Password in Android

Tags: android, password-storage

I am developing an android application that allows access to its contents when the user enters the password.
I do not want to include a database, i just want the application to be able to create a new password for the user and also the user can be able to change the old password to a new one.

I have created two classes and one xml. But what i want now is to make the EdittextPreference pop up 3 edittext rather than the usual 1 so that the user can be able to change the old password. See the code so far

```
<EditTextPreference android:key="showPreferences"
    android:title="Preferences"
    android:summary="Admin Data"
    android:defaultValue="Nothing"/>

<EditTextPreference android:key="editPassword"
    android:title="Change Password"
    android:summary="This allows you to change password"
    android:defaultValue="Nothing"/>
```

package my.preferences;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SetPrefs extends PreferenceActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Store user password in `Shared Preference..`

The **SharedPreferences** class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. **This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).**

[Android - Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 1):

You can store username and password in a file and encrypt it's content and decrypt that when you need it. Shared preference is another good option you can choose

[Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170967&seqNum=4) is an example of how to encrypt and how to decrypt something:

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want database then, `SharedPreferene` to store passwords.
For code, please show your effort.